# How to turn a PySpark dataframe to a nested dict

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I have this PySpark dataframe of flight details:

```
+----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------+
|   fs_date|   ss_date|fs_origin|fs_destination|    price|
+----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------+
|2022-06-01|2022-06-02|      TLV|           AUH| 681.0715|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-03|      TLV|           AUH|   406.46|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-04|      TLV|           AUH| 393.0465|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-02|      TLV|           BAK|    457.7|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-03|      TLV|           BAK|  348.075|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-05|      TLV|           BAK|    475.7|
```

I want to transform it to a nested dict like so:

```py
{

   'TLV-AUH': {
                 '2022-06-01:2022-06-02': 681.0715,
                 '2022-06-01:2022-06-03': 406.46,
                 '2022-06-01:2022-06-04': 393.0465
              },

   'TLV-BAK': {
                 '2022-06-01:2022-06-02': 457.7,
                 '2022-06-01:2022-06-03': 348.075,
                 '2022-06-01:2022-06-05': 475.7
              }

}
```

Comment: have you tried anything from the answers of your previous question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73213608/collect-pyspark-dataframe-into-list-of-dictionaries-by-value

Comment: I've tried, but I couldn't get the wanted output...

Comment: please feel free to share what you tried and we can help you build on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the schema which can be picked by rdd's `asDict()`

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2022-06-01', '2022-06-02', 'TLV', 'AUH', 681.0715),
     ('2022-06-01', '2022-06-03', 'TLV', 'AUH', 406.46),
     ('2022-06-01', '2022-06-04', 'TLV', 'AUH', 393.0465),
     ('2022-06-01', '2022-06-02', 'TLV', 'BAK', 457.7),
     ('2022-06-01', '2022-06-03', 'TLV', 'BAK', 348.075),
     ('2022-06-01', '2022-06-05', 'TLV', 'BAK', 475.7)],
    ['fs_date', 'ss_date', 'fs_origin', 'fs_destination', 'price'])
```

Script:

```py
df = (df
    .groupBy(F.concat_ws('-', 'fs_origin', 'fs_destination').alias('from_to'))
    .agg(F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_set(F.struct(F.concat_ws(':', 'fs_date', 'ss_date'), 'price'))
    ).alias('map'))
)
df = df.groupBy().pivot('from_to').agg(F.first('map'))

my_dict = df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.asDict()).collect()[0]
# {
#   'TLV-AUH': {
#     '2022-06-01:2022-06-04': 393.0465,
#     '2022-06-01:2022-06-03': 406.46,
#     '2022-06-01:2022-06-02': 681.0715
#   },
#   'TLV-BAK': {
#     '2022-06-01:2022-06-03': 348.075,
#     '2022-06-01:2022-06-02': 457.7,
#     '2022-06-01:2022-06-05': 475.7
#   }
# }
```

Comment: Great!
Is there an option to keep the order of the dates? (2022-06-01:2022-06-02, 2022-06-01:2022-06-03, 2022-06-01:2022-06-04) etc...

Comment: I've tried with "orderBy("fs_destination", "fs_date", "ss_date")" before the "groupBy()" but it didn't work...

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you can do it in Python. Or maybe someone else has a better alternative.

Comment: used this plain python code to solve it, I belive there's a way of doing it using pyspark.. 
data_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(data_dict.items()))
for key, value in data_dict.items():
    data_dict[key] = OrderedDict(sorted(value.items()))